# Clarifying the meaning of insolvability of quintic

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, quintics

Insolvability of quintic says that no analogue of quadratic formula is available for quintic equations. For quadratic equations, the formula $x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ gives you all the roots of $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ for any choice of $a$, $b$, $c$. Let us work on a field $F$ with algebraic closure $\overline{F}$.

Formulas like $x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ can be interpreted in two ways. First way, one interpret $\sqrt \cdot$ as a fixed function $\sqrt \cdot \colon \overline{F} \to \overline{F}$. In this case, $\pm$ is necessary. Second way, one interpret $\sqrt \cdot$ as a multivalued function $\sqrt \cdot \colon \overline{F} \to \mathcal{P}(\overline{F})$. In this case, $\pm$ is unnecessary and one formula $x = \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ gives you all the roots.

For the first interpretation one can formulate the insolvability of quintic like this: There doesn't exist a function $f\colon F^5 \to \overline{F}$ which

- can be expressed with $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, and for any $n$ any function $\sqrt[n]{\cdot}\colon \overline{F} \to \overline{F}$ satisfying $(\sqrt[n]{x})^n = x$ for every $x \in \overline{F}$
- and $x = f(a, b, c, d, e)$ is a root of polynomial equation $x^5 + ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0$.

How could one connect this formulation to the usual Galois theoretic proof of insolvability of quintic? For quadratic equations $x^2 + ax + b = 0$, we know that $f(a, b) := \frac{-a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}$ satisfies the condition for any choice of $\sqrt \cdot$. Now one can find an analouge $f^\bullet \in \overline{F(a, b)}$ corresponding to $f$. Preciesly, one can pick a square root of $a^2 - 4b$ in the algebraic closure of $F(a, b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are indeterminates, and consider $f^\bullet := \frac{-a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}$. We know that $f^\bullet$ is a solution of the polynomial equation $x^2 + ax + b = 0$. In this setting one can apply Galois theoretic approaches about field extensions of $F(a, b)$.

The key is, in this case not only $f$ is numerically correct (gives a correct root for any choice of $a, b$), but it is also symbolically correct (the analogue $f^\bullet$ is a solution of the euqation). So I think if one can prove that any numerically correct formula is also symbolically correct, the formulation above can be proven by the usual Galois theoretic proof.

Are my thoughts correct? If correct, then how could one prove that any numerically correct formula is also symbolically correct?

Edit: Some attempt by my acquaintance:
Let $f$ be a numerically correct formula for $n$th degree polynomial equation and $f^\bullet$ be the analogue in $\overline{F(a_0, \ldots, a_{n - 1})}$. Let $A := F[a_0, \ldots, a_{n - 1}]$ and $K$ be a finite extension of $F(a_0, \ldots, a_{n - 1})$ containing $f^\bullet$. Let $p \in A[x]$ be the polynomial $x^n + a_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} + \ldots + a_0$. Now let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $K$. Then $B$ is a finite $A$-module, thus finitely generated over $F$. Localize $B$ by an appropriate element $g \in A$ so that $f^\bullet \in B_g$, and $B_g$ is still finitely generated over $F$. Since $J(B_g) = 0$, it suffices to prove that $p(f^\bullet) \in M$ for every maximal ideal $M$ of $B_g$. $B_g/M$ embeds into $\overline{F}$, and $f^\bullet$ seems to be mapped to an evaluation of the function $f$ at a point $b_0, \ldots, b_{n - 1} \in \overline{F}$. If one can prove the last sentence, we are done for algebraically closed fields. Actually there are some additional difficulties here, since $f$ chooses arbitrary branch when extracting $n$-th root.

Edit 2: Giving a particular insolvable polynomial wouldn't work when $F$ is algebraically closed. Here I am referring to the Galois theoretic proof of insolvability of general polynomial. Also, if $F$ is a finite field, there would be trivially a numerically correct solution, so I think this question would be interesting when there are some restriction on $F$, for example algebraically closed.

Clarification: The usual Galois theoretic proof I'm referring to is that for indeterminates $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $x^5 + ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0$ is not solvable by radicals in $F(a, b, c, d, e)$ since the splitting field has Galois group $S_5$.

Edit 3: The problem here is that $f^\bullet$ is **not** a function, in contrast to $f$. This is like the distinction between a formal polynomial and a polynomial function. In contrast to polynomials, there isn't such a thing as evaluation homomorphism $\overline{F(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n - 1})} \to \overline{F}$, because it would be an embedding, which is impossible (nevertheless the idea in Edit 1 is an attempt to evaluate such things). By the usual Galois theoretic proof, nonexistance of $f^\bullet$ can be established, but it doesn't directly imply nonexistance of $f$. As I said eariler, when $F$ is finite, this is not the case. There must be a distinction between numerical correctness and symbolical correctness. One should require some condition on $F$ (e.g. algebraically closed) to prove that there exists no **function** satisfying given conditions. This is not a statement about **elements** of $\overline{F(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n - 1})}$. This is the reason I asked *how could one prove that any numerically correct formula is also symbolically correct?*. For example, when $F$ is infinite, two polynomials are equal iff the related polynomial functions are equal. This is an example of connection between numerical correctness and symbolical correctness. As suggested in the comments, I should read some original proofs rather than the proof I'm referring to.

Comment: I also wondered about this, which led to [this 14 January 2001 sci.math.symbolic post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math.symbolic/c/i-JpkrLxU9g/m/BulWPazv76kJ) and 2 follow-ups. Within 3 years I pretty much resolved these concerns (e.g. one byway led to solvability by real radicals -- see [this 26 September 2005 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/L0q4dXJAEuk/m/djqrg7ZXqGcJ); another byway led to [this manuscript](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316692623_A_detailed_and_elementary_solution_to_x17_1)), but maybe my 2001 questions on this topic will be of interest.

Comment: The meaning of solvability via radicals is handled by the notion of radical extensions which is itself a field theoretic translation of what Abel described in his proof (algebraic functions of a particular degree). The radicals involved are inherently multivalued. Galois goes a step further and gives a framework which handles all polynomials and not just "general"  polynomials with symbolic coefficients.

Comment: Galois theory can handle polynomials with symbolic coefficients like $x^2+ax+b$ as well as the ones with numeric coefficients like $x^2+2x+3$ by changing the base field. In first case the polynomial is treated as belonging to $\mathbb{C} (a, b) [x] $ and in the other case the polynomial belongs to $\mathbb{Q} [x] $. Apart from this there is no difference in handling of specific and general polynomials. And the problem turns out to be more difficult when one is dealing with specific polynomials.

Comment: Galois mentions the difference between symbolic and numeric coefficients and says that substitution of symbolic coefficients via numerical ones changes the Galois group and in effect one has to start over again. In short such a substitution does not work.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I don't get your point. I am not interested in whether a particular polynomial has a solution, but whether there is a function which is universally correct for every such polynomial. There is a proof that the general polynomial is insolvable, but this doesn't directly imply that there doesn't exist such *function*. So I wanted to know how to connect between them.

Comment: The proof that that general polynomials of degree $5$ or higher are insolvable by radicals is about the non-existence of the functions (like you have described). Ruffini, Abel, Galois all proved this non-existence using different approaches. However a common theme uniting these approaches is the permutation of roots of polynomials.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh No. For example if $F$ is finite there exists such a function. There is clearly a distinction between numerical correctness and symbolical correctness. The usual Galois theoretic proof we know claims that there doesn't exist an *element* in a solvable extension of $F(a_0, \ldots, a_{n - 1})$, not a *function*.

Comment: Let's be clear that Ruffini, Abel and Galois were dealing with field of complex numbers (the $F$ in your question is $\mathbb{C} $ for them) in their proofs. And all of them proved the non-existence of such functions in this context.

Comment: In particular let's also note the key theorem by Abel (theorem of natural irrationalities) that any such functions must be expressible as rational functions of the roots.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ok. It seems it would be beneficial to look into the original proofs.

Comment: Abel-Ruffini proof is discussed in detail in my blog posts : [post 1](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/12/abel-and-the-insolvability-of-the-quintic-part-1.html?m=0), [post 2](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/01/abel-and-the-insolvability-of-the-quintic-part-2.html?m=0), [post 3](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/01/abel-and-the-insolvability-of-the-quintic-part-3.html?m=0) and [post 4](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/01/abel-and-the-insolvability-of-the-quintic-part-4.html?m=0).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Are there any accessible document demonstrating Abel's proof which deals with raw functions instead of modernized version? Should I read the original paper?

Comment: I still don't understand what there is to check. Existence of such functions would imply solutions of particular insoluble polynomials - impossible. End of story, no?

Comment: @FShrike As I said in Edit 2, let $F$ be algebraically closed, say $\mathbb{C}$. There are no insolvable polynomials now. Or, if $F$ finite, then there is such a function now. For fields like $\mathbb{Q}$ that argument works.

Comment: Also I wanted to apply the insolvability of general polynomial, which is what I said in the clarification, not using a particular insolvable instance.

Comment: You wanted to connect your formulation to the usual proof. The usual proof obviously doesn't try to prove there are unsolvable polynomials over $\Bbb C$, it talks about $\Bbb Q$

Comment: @FShrike No. I didn't refer to that proof. See my "clarification" please. I am repeatedly saying that I'm not interested in proving with insolvability of a particular quintic. I think I'll not argue about this anymore.

Comment: "How could one connect this formulation to the usual Galois theoretic proof of insolvability of quintic? "

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is, how do you define "can be expressed with"?

The Galois-theoretic theorem and proof states the problem *precisely* as:

> For a given field $F$ and a given polynomial $f\in F[x]$, does there exist a series of field extensions $F\subset F_1\subset F_2\subset\cdots\subset F_n$, with each $F_{i+1}$ being isomorphic to $F_i(\sqrt[m_i]{a_i})$ for some $m_i\in\Bbb N$ and $a_i\in F_i$, such that $F_n$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $F$?

The precise statement of field extensions by adjoining radicals captures the idea of a "formula involving only radicals". For in the above situation, all the roots of $f$ would lie in $F_n$ and every element of $F_n$ can be obtained through applying field operations and (nested) radicals to elements of $F$. If a quintic formula existed, say, for $F=\Bbb Q$, that would in particular imply every quintic over $\Bbb Q$ has a splitting field extension of the above form. The Galois-theoretic proof of the unsolvability of the quintic is, more precisely, a proof that there are quintic (and higher) polynomials over $\Bbb Q$ whose splitting field extension **cannot** be broken down into a tower of radical extensions.

In particular, a "general formula" would imply every quintic has some kind of associated canonical series of extensions as described above, but there are polynomials for which no such tower exists, canonical or otherwise.

Comment: What I meant with "can be expressed with" would be formalized as taking the minimal family of functions which is closed under the given operations. Also I was referring to the proof of insolvability of *general* quintic, not a particular quintic. A proof for a particular quintic would indeed prove that there exists no numerically correct formula.

Comment: @JoshuaKwon The insolubility of the general quintic is precisely the statement that there are quintics which cannot be "solved"

Comment: No. This wiki page about [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) mentions the difference between them

Comment: Actually, I see your point. The Galois-theoretic statement is a stronger statement than the one you're trying to make. Not only is there no general formula, but there are no formulas at all for a wide class of quintics.

Comment: So, your point is there exists a quintic polynomial equation which is not solvable (in the usual Galois theoretical sense), so there couldn't exist such $f$. I also agree, as I said "a proof for a particular quintic would indeed prove that there exists no numerically correct formula." But I wanted to know if the proof about general quintic equation can be applied to my formulation.

Comment: @JoshuaKwon I don't know what you mean by numerically correct here. There just is no correct formula, at all

Comment: For example, the *function* $f(a, b)$ given for quadratic equation holds for every choice of $a$ and $b$, and this is what I called as numerically correct.
On the other hand, $f^\bullet$ is an *element* in the algebraic closure of $F(a, b)$, where $a$, $b$ are indeterminates. If we plug in $f^\bullet$ at the place of $x$ and compute in $\overline{F(a, b)}$, it works. This is what I called as symbolically correct.
The usual Galois theoretic proof about general quintic euqation says that there exists no symbolically correct formula, not about numerically correct formula

Comment: ...so I wanted to know if one can connect this two notions.

Comment: I don't feel like you have a precise definition of "numerically" versus "symbolically" correct. A given element of $\overline{F}$ - it either is or isn't a root of the polynomial. An "expression" gives you a root, or it doesn't. I don't see what the point is

Comment: The point is that $f^\bullet$ is **not** a function, in contrast to $f$. It does not give you elements of $\overline{F}$. It is like the difference between a polynomial function and a formal polynomial.

Comment: Neither $f^{\bullet}\in\overline{F(a,b,c,d,e)}$ nor $f:F^5\to\overline{F}$ can exist with $F=\Bbb Q$. $f^{\bullet}$ fails to exist in general because the substitution homomorphism, for specific values of $a,b,c,d,e$, would create a contradiction with the usual statement, and $f$ cannot exist because again, the evaluation $f(a,b,c,d,e)$ would result in a similar contradiction (a solution to a insoluble quintic via radicals). And we can say more than that, not only do no general forms $f,f^{\bullet}$ exist but no specific formulas can exist either @JoshuaKwon

Comment: But how do you construct the substitution homomorphism? It has some problems like singularity, and branch selection. On the other hand, yes, you are right. But what I wanted to know is, if we have a proof that $f^\bullet$ can not exist, could one apply this fact to prove that $f$ also couldn't exist? That is, can we apply the Galois theoretic proof that symbolically correct formula doesn't exist to prove that numerically correct formula also doesn't exist?

Comment: I wonder whether what's going on here is that any field that contains one solution of a quadratic contains both solutions, whereas a field can contain one solution of a quintic without containing any of the other four. But that situation already comes up with cubic and quartic equations, which are solvable in radicals, but where a field containing one root need not contain others.